# Nesting MUI grid inside stack with spacing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Nesting an MUI `Grid` (container) inside an MUI `Stack` (with `spacing` applied) causes issues with margin styles. Since the `Stack` automatically "voids" all margin applied to its children (to allow for its own spacing margin), and the `Grid` container requires negative margin to layout properly, using the two together results in shifted layouts (mainly horizontally). Is there a nice way to get around this, other than having to avoid using a `Stack` parent with spacing, and applying said spacing manually to all children? This seems like a relatively common use case, and I was hoping to find a way to disable the `Stack` from "voiding" its child item's margins?

---

This does not work, because the parent `Stack` "voids" the child grid's negative margin, in order to apply its own spacing margin (only vertical).

```js
<Stack spacing={2}>
  <Grid container spacing={3}>
    <Grid item>...</Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid container>...</Grid>
  <WhateverElse />
</Stack>
```

```
.css-1lwbda4-MuiStack-root>:not(style)+:not(style){
  margin:0;margin-top:24px;
}
```

---

This works, because the parent `Stack` does not specify `spacing`, which allows children to keep their margins (negative margins in case of `Grid`).

````
<Stack>
  <Grid container spacing={3}>
    <Grid item>...</Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid container>...</Grid>
  <WhateverElse />
</Stack>```
````